# How should I make Multicolored progress bar work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a multicolored `progress bar` where I want to show the progress with incremental percentage value and respective color.

I am able to fetch the data from `JSON` and plot the `progress bar` but `setInterval` function is not working.

Currently I am writing the `setInterval` function inside the for loop.
For that may be its not working.

Please help me out on this and let me know if any other approaches is there.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #dist_bar {
        height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #222;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="dist_bar"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var json_data = [

        {
          "color": "red",
          "percentage": 30,
          "speed": 10,

        }, {
          "color": "yellow",
          "percentage": 20,
          "speed": 10,

        }

      ]


      function draw_ProgressBar(parms) {

        var arrayLength = json_data.length;
        var progress = setInterval(progress, 1000);
        var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
          var docid = document.getElementById('dist_bar');
          var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
          innerDiv.id = 'dist' + i;
          dist_bar.appendChild(innerDiv);

          innerDiv.style.height = "30px";
          innerDiv.style.float = "left";
          innerDiv.style.backgroundColor = json_data[i].color;

          var p = 0; //var percent = '';
          var percent = json_data[i].percentage;
          var inc = setInterval(progress,10);
          (function progress(i) {

          if (p != percent) {

            for (var j = 0; j < percent; j++) {
              p++;
              var val = document.getElementById('dist' + i);
              val.innerHTML = p + "%";
              val.style.width = p + "%";
            }
          } else {

            clearInterval(progress);
          }
        }(i));
      } 
  }draw_ProgressBar(json_data)

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default

Comment: The code is incomplete, where is the function progress?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Progress function is there.